# How to test in Jest a class method's was used was when the class is a parameter to the function being tested, not a module?

Tags: javascript, class, jestjs, es6-class

index.js

```
class myClass { } 

makeClass(myClass)
```

make-class.js:

```
const callback = () => { // do something }

const makeClass = (myClass) => {
   new myClass();

   class.method(callback)
}
```

make.class.test.js

```
    const mockedCallback = () => { }
     const mockedClass = jest.fn();
     mockedClass.mockReturnValue(({
        method: () => callback
     })):
    
     makeClass(mockedClass);
    
     // expects class constructor to have been called 
    
    
  expect(mockedClass).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
   // expect a single instance to have been created 
expect(mockedClass.mock.instances).toHaveLength(1);
```

> The above test **passes with or without the `new` keyword** in the function to test. so it's not effectively showing we instantiated the class.

```
// expect the method `method` of myClass's instance to have been called 
expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

The above test **fails** ( callback() not defined and in fact `mockedClass.mock.instances[0]` exists but it is an **empty array**.
A spy might help here, but not sure how it would  work as **the class is a parameter, not a module.**

---

How to solve the 2 problems highlighted? (the last 2 tests)

Comment: Why don't you pass an *actual class*? You don't have to use jest.fn to create your test doubles.

Comment: @jonrsharpe with an actual class some of the tests fail.

Comment: Which tests? You've only shown some of the body of one test, can you give a [mre]?